# how to test range age in postman

Tags: json, postman

```
pm.test("Age for apply a job", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    pm.expect(jsonData.resume.age).to.eql(jsonData.jobPosting.lowerBoundAge && jsonData.jobPosting.upperBoundAge);
});
```

I want to test ages between 25-40 but this code can test the only age

jsonData.resume.age = 24

jsonData.jobPosting.lowerBoundAge = 25

jsonData.jobPosting.upperBoundAge = 40

Answer (score 3):

You can use the chaiJS [within](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/) method in the assertion:

```
pm.expect(jsonData.resume.age).to.be.within(jsonData.jobPosting.lowerBoundAge, jsonData.jobPosting.upperBoundAge);
```

You could tidy this up and create local variables for each item but this should hopefully give you the general idea.

Comment: Can you accept this as the answer please, if it solved your problem 

Comment: @p_theoneyouknow https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/ postman uses chai so you can refer  this link to see other things you can use